# How to fill DataTable rows only if primary key is bigger than last primary key?

Tags: c#, json, datatable

The problem: inserting rows only **if primary key is bigger than existing one** when merging source DataTable to actual DataTable (`ActualDT.Merge(SourceDT)`).

Details of my problem below:

I fill an Actual DataTable with an `Int64` primary key by the API from external server after deserializing JSON to Source DataTable. Then I write rows from DataTable to my database and cleanup all rows in DataTable except the biggest primary key. Later I request new data from the API and often the response contains the same rows I already wrote to database and cleanup from my DataTable.

If I won't cleanup the DataTable rows, performance decrease and it's memory pig. So, I leave one row with the biggest primary key after cleaning.

I don't want to compare every PrimaryKey from Source DataTable before merge, comparing can take a lot of time.

What should I do to prevent merging rows that I already wrote to database and removed from Actual DataTable? Maybe I can exclude them even at deserialisation process (I use NewtonSoft JSON.net)? Or any zippy way to prevent merging rows if they primary key  < primary key in Actual DataTable?

Thanks for your answers!

**UPDATE**: merging code

```
public class MyData
{
    DataTable BlackPairs = new DataTable();
    DataTable WhiteTable = new DataTable();

    public string _Json {

        set
        {
            DataSet TempDS = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DataSet>(value);
            try
            {
                foreach (DataTable table in TempDS.Tables)
                {
                    BlackPairs = table.Copy();
                    WhiteTable.Merge(BlackPairs);
                }
            }catch{}
        }
    }

    public MyData()
    {   //columns initialization
        WhiteTable.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[]{columns);
        WhiteTable.PrimaryKey = new DataColumn[]{tid};
    }
```

Comment: Could you post `merge function` code. You can make that inside it

Comment: @AleksaRistic, I have update post with example

Comment: Need `merge function` code

Comment: @AleksaRistic, WhiteTable.Merge(BlackPairs); this is merge function, standard for System.Data in C#. Or what function do you mean?

Comment: One more question. Are columns same in both tables?

Comment: @AleksaRistic, yep. They are the same

Comment: Look at my answer it will do the job

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have created custom `Merge` function based on what we have talked through comments. This function is only if primary column is `typeof(int)` but it can be easily improved to get all types or just change it to what type you need (string, int, bool...)

```
public Test()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataTable smallerDatatable = new DataTable();
    smallerDatatable.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(int));
    smallerDatatable.Columns.Add("Col2", typeof(string));

    DataTable biggerDatatable = new DataTable();
    biggerDatatable.Columns.Add("Col1", typeof(int));
    biggerDatatable.Columns.Add("Col2", typeof(string));

    smallerDatatable.Rows.Add(1, "Row1");
    smallerDatatable.Rows.Add(2, "Row2");
    smallerDatatable.Rows.Add(3, "Row3");
    biggerDatatable.Rows.Add(1, "Row1");
    biggerDatatable.Rows.Add(2, "Row2");
    biggerDatatable.Rows.Add(3, "Row3");
    biggerDatatable.Rows.Add(4, "Row4");
    biggerDatatable.Rows.Add(5, "Row5");

    DataTable mergedTable = MergeOnUniqueColumn(smallerDatatable, biggerDatatable, "Col1");
    dataGridView1.DataSource = mergedTable;
}

private DataTable MergeOnUniqueColumn(DataTable smallTable, DataTable bigTable, string uniqueColumn)
{
    DataTable m = smallTable;
    for(int i = 0; i < bigTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if(!(smallTable.AsEnumerable().Any(row => bigTable.Rows[i][uniqueColumn].Equals(row.Field<object>(uniqueColumn)))))
        {
            smallTable.Rows.Add(bigTable.Rows[i].ItemArray);
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

Function above will fill every missing unique value inside `smallTable` from `bigTable`.

If you want to fill `smallTable` with values from `bigTable` only after last `smallTable` row then use this function.

```
private DataTable MergeOnUniqueColumnAfterLastID(DataTable smallTable, DataTable bigTable, string uniqueColumn)
{
    DataTable m = smallTable;
    int maxUnique = Convert.ToInt32(m.Compute("max([" + uniqueColumn + "])", string.Empty));
    for (int i = 0; i < bigTable.Rows.Count; i++)
    {
        if (!(smallTable.AsEnumerable().Any(row => (int)bigTable.Rows[i][uniqueColumn] <= maxUnique)))
        {
            smallTable.Rows.Add(bigTable.Rows[i].ItemArray);
        }
    }
    return m;
}
```

Comment: if `smallerDataTable` doesn't exist Row1 and Row2, it's still merge Row1 and Row2 to `smallerDataTable` from `biggerDataTable`. I look zippy way to clean Row1 and Row2 from smallerDataTable and paste rows from `biggerDataTable` only after Row3.

Comment: If i get it you do not want to insert only if `uniqueColumn` value doesn't exist in `smallTable` but only if it is bigger than `smallTable max uniqueColumn value`?

Comment: @ИванПогосов i have edited answer and added new function that you will use instead of the old one

Comment: Yep :-) Also col1 int increments random value (after 1000 can go 1020, not 1001). ForExample in smallerTable  col1.row1=1, col1.row2=3, col1.row3 = 10; If biggerDataTable contain rows col1.row1=9 and col2.row2=12, only col1.row2 needs to be merged from biggerDataTable to smallerDataTable. In result, smallerDataTable will contain row1=1, row=3, row3=10, row4=12.

Comment: Looks like good solution! At least it's doing works :) I will measure performance later, maybe I can improve it. A lot of thanks to you!